# How to unsubscribe from Redis client just after first message received using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have a Redis server into AWS ElastiCache. Publishing message into the Redis channel.
And trying to get the message by subscribing.
I am using Javascript sample like below.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var subscriber = redis.createClient(port = 6379, host = "localhost");
subscriber.subscribe('my_channel');
subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
});
```

The received message are printing by the console.log()

Now the problem is, above sample print message continuously as the message is publishing continuously.
But I want to unsubscribe just after received a single message.
How can I achieve that?

Also one more point is how to bring out the message outside of subscriber.on() function?

I have Googled bit, but couldn't found any helpful post. But if there is any related post please share.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use counter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on the example of the [node-redis docs](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#example-2):

```
const redis = require("redis");

const subscriber = redis.createClient();

let messageCount = 0;

subscriber.on("message", function(channel, message) {
  messageCount += 1;

  console.log("Subscriber received message in channel '" + channel + "': " + message);

  if (messageCount === 2) {
    subscriber.unsubscribe();
    subscriber.quit();
  }
});

subscriber.subscribe("my_channel");
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I also found the same example and already solved my issue.
Thanks again.